# How to display or show Google Maps in Appcelerator Titanium - Android app (Error : The Google Play services resources were not found)

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator

I need insert gmaps on my app in appcelerator. I do all by this guide http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android

In tiapp.xml :

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".Activity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" >
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="!MY_API_KEY!"/>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
    <services>
        <service type="interval" url="service.js"/>
    </services>
</android>
```

In controlller:

```
var Map = require('ti.map');

var mountainView = Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    myid:1 // Custom property to uniquely identify this annotation.
});

var mapview = Map.createView({
    mapType: Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});

var circle = Map.createCircle({
    center: { latitude: 33.74511, longitude: -84.38993 },
    radius: 1000, //1km
    fillColor: "#20FF0000"
});
mapview.addCircle(circle);

// Handle click events on any annotations on this map.
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info("Clicked " + evt.clicksource + " on " + evt.latitude + "," + evt.longitude);
});

$.item.add(mapview);
```

But i get this error:

```
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping hread
    [ERROR] :  SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
    [WARN] :   chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)]                                                                            locale_file_path.empty()
    [ERROR] :  libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    [ERROR] :  libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    [WARN] :   AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
    [ERROR] :  DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [WARN] :   art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
    [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-14) [1560,1630] HTTP Error (java.io.IOException): 404 : Not Found
    [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: java.io.IOException: 404 : Not Found
    [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1217)
    [ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    [INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    [WARN] :   chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
    [ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Cannot find Google Play services package name.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsh.getPackageInfo(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzby(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzbx(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzbt(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzai.zzdq(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzai.zzdp(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzbru(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.ja        va:1613)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
    [ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
    [ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
    [ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
    [ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    [WARN] :   GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [200,1830] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;; Titanium 6.0.0,2016/11/13 01:23,undefined
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzi(Unknown Source)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.r70.avtospravka-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.r70.avtospravka-2/lib/x86, /data/app/ru.r70.avtospravka-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   ... 18 more
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.R$string
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:       ... 19 more
    [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
    [ERROR] :  W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1654): Timed out waiting on                       IInputContextCallback
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not Google Play Services SDK installed in your Android SDK.

You can check whether the Play Services SDK is installed or not using **[isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map-method-isGooglePlayServicesAvailable)** method.

Before proceeding further, make sure that you have Play Services SDK, look at this section **[Google Play Services](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android-section-src-36739898_GoogleMapsv2forAndroid-InstalltheGooglePlayServicesSDK)** to install it.

Also note that Google Play Services SDK may not be found at the exact location because Google has implemented a different way to keep play services sdk files at many locations.

Best way to check whether the services are installed or not is to look for them using **Android SDK Manager** and then go to **Extras** dropdown.

[image]

Comment: In Android SDK Manager Google play services is checked. But isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()  return 
[ERROR] :  GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Comment: You mean that in SDK Manager, it is Installed(or Update available), not just left-blue checked?

Sometimes, Google Play Services are actually installed but app does not detect it, I had this issue during Push implementation, so the fix was to create another project with same app id (TAKE BACKUP FIRST) and clear the Cache & Storage of previous app and then delete it from device.

Also, you can try it on a different device to know the actual issue in less time.

Answer (score 1):

the permission and map-key insert in the `<Application>` not in `<Activity>`

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="!MY_API_KEY!"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Activity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```